# React-Native social auth with NodeJS MongoDB

Tags: node.js, oauth, react-native

I want to implement a react-native app with social login (google, FB) only. I am not clear about the complete flow though.

I can use various react-native modules that are available for oauth based login from Google. I don't know what to do with the information I get back. For example, If I need to create a todo app, I would want to store the user email and task created on my local server. After obtaining the email from google, I can make an api call and store data into my server using email but that won't be secure enough.

How does this kind of flow usually work. Usually in web based social login, callback url will provide info to the server directly. How does it work without using WebView?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.